# React.js how to draw items in cycle for

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I have a function to draw items in cycle for, I need to draw 5 items, but it draws just first one**

Function:

```
export default function CinemaHole() {

   for(let i = i; i < 5; i++) {
       return (
           <div className="hole">
               <h1>{i}</h1>
           </div>
      )   
   }  

}
```

Comment: for(let i = 1; i < 5; i++) typo

Comment: Once you `return` the rest of the loop won't be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns on the first iteration of the loop and function execution gets completed.

If you need to add five div tags to the DOM, append all the div to an array and return the array.

Also, if you put i=1 and i<5, the loop will iterate 4 items with the values as 1, 2, 3, 4. If you want to iterate 5 times consider declaring i as 0 or increase the condition limit.

```
export default function CinemaHole() {

    const holes = []

    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        holes.push(
            <div className="hole">
                <h1>{i}</h1>
            </div>
        )   
    }  

    return holes

}
```